# Toggle button - Variable

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make a button which when I click returns false or true.
I saw many buttons when I searched but none in java, they either were in JQuery which I don't understand or they weren't what I looked for.

I basically made a var "onOff = 1", and when I press it I want it to turn false if its true, and if its false I want it to turn true. My current setup doesn't work at all.

```
   var onOff = 1;

function toggle(button){
  if(onOff = 1){
   onOff = 0;
   }

  else if(onOff = 0){
   onOff = 1;
   }
}
```

I want to make it work with this, or some other button for testing and learning purposes.

```
    <form action="">
<input type="button" id="1" value="ON" style="color:blue"
       onclick="toggle(this);">
```

Comment: If condition is wrong.

Comment: = `!==` == that's all

Comment: Additionally, use booleans, not numbers.

Comment: `=` - assignment, `==` and `===` - equality

Comment: Thanks got it :) U guys made me feel like a silly baboon!

Answer (score 2):

Got a snippet with the correct function, Var onOff has to be true, if it's false it wont run, otherwise works nice.

```js
var onOff = true;

function toggle(button) {
  if (document.getElementById("1").value == "False" && onOff == false) {
    document.getElementById("1").value = "True"
    onOff = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("1").value == "True" && onOff == true) {

    document.getElementById("1").value = "False";
    onOff = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="button" id="1" value="True" style="color:blue" onclick="toggle(this);">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the variable `true` or `false` to start, then set it to the opposite of that:

```
var onOff = true;
function toggle() {
    onOff = !onOff
}
```

*Also, Java != JavaScript*